# Change background color of an element of a ListView after tapping it, causes color changing in other elements

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

Good day to all! Here is my problem:

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. When the user decides to select (tap) one of the elements, I make the background of the chosen element becoming green. If the user wants to deselect that same element (by tapping it again), I make the background changing color from green to grey. **The problem here is that if the user select, let's say, the 4th element, it becomes green, but 9th - 14th - 19th and so became green to**. I'm pretty sure that this problem is related to the view recycling. So I made an holder to keep informations about each view, but still the things go wrong... Here is the code:

**MainActivity class:**

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
final AdapterForListView listAdapter = new AdapterForListView(this, R.layout.todo_list_maker, types);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {

        String data = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

        View view;
        int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int lastPosition = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();

        if (position >= firstPosition && position <= lastPosition) {
            view = listView.getChildAt(position - firstPosition);

            if (view.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder) {
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                if(holder.Color.equals("green")){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(0xababab);
                    holder.Color = "grey";
                }
                else{
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    holder.Color = "green";
                }
            }
        } else {
            view = listView.getChildAt(position);

            if (view.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder) {
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                if(holder.Color.equals("green")){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(0xababab);
                    holder.Color = "grey";
                }
                else{
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    holder.Color = "green";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Now here is the adapter:**

```
public class AdapterForListView extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private String[] object;

    public AdapterForListView(Context context, int position, String[] object){
        super(context, position, object);
        this.context=context;
        this.object=object;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;             //trying to reuse a recycled view
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list_maker, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textTypes);
            holder.Color = "grey";

            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        String t = object[position];
        if(t != null) {
            // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
            holder.tvName.setText(t);
        }

        return row;

    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvName;
        String Color;
    }
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: What is your minimum supported API level? if 16, you can try `View.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#664455")).mutate());`

Comment: Minimum: 14
Target: 16

Unfortunately I haven't a good smartphone